# What would cause Log-Log Plot to be Non-linear?

Tags: graphing-functions, finite-element-method, error-propagation

I'm attempting to plot the error of a simulation compared to an analytical solution and am curious if my problem is intrinsic to my model or the way I am plotting the results.

The idea is that my log-log plot should produce a line with a slope of 1 showing that the rate of convergence is first-order. I am currently refering to a text called: *Finite Element Analysis, from concepts to applications* by David S. Burnett in Chapter 9.

My analytical solution is as follows:

$$
f(x) = \frac{(3e+8 \cdot x)}{6} \cdot (0.01 - x) + (600 - 300) \cdot \frac{x}{0.01} + 300
$$

Where $x$ is position along a 1-D bar of 0.01m length. I am then computing the error like:

$$
\text{Error} = \log_{10}\left(\frac{U-\tilde{U}}{U}\right)
$$

Where $U$ is the analytical solution and $\tilde{U}$ is the simulated solution.

Below is a table of data displaying the results of my simulation run at the position of $0.00252242$. `pos_random` is the simulated solution at that position while `t_sol` is the analytical solution. `t_err` is the error.

```
   model_id  log_model_id   pos_random        t_sol      t_err     slope
1         1       0.00000   375.672600  1318.752467  -0.145615  0.000000
1         2      -0.30103  1006.277600  1318.752467  -0.625348  1.593640
1         4      -0.60206  1315.975100  1318.752467  -2.676530  6.813878
1         8      -0.90309  1317.376350  1318.752467  -2.981508  1.013115
1        16      -1.20412  1318.076975  1318.752467  -3.290543  1.026592
1     10000      -4.00000  1318.752467  1318.752467 -10.251518  2.489726
```

This data produces the plot below:

[image]

As you can see, the plot created does not display a continuously linear line. This goes against the text I am reading as well as does not follow 1st order model as the slope should be near 1. I am wondering if there is something wrong with my approach or if this is something that is probably intrinsic to my model design. Any help is greatly appreciated. If this is the wrong exchange please let me know.

Comment: I suspect the problem is numerical error (roundoff, division by a small denominator, ...) in the first two simulations. pos_random there looks very strange. Can you calculate for powers of $2$ between $16$ and $10000$?

Comment: @EthanBolker `model_id` is the number of elements in my model and `log_model_id` is defined as `log10(1/model_id)`. Apologies, I'm kind of a n00b at this, what exactly do you mean "calculate for powers of 2 between 16-10000"?

Comment: Without knowing more about what this is a model of, I suspect that when there are few "elements" there is some instability in the simulation. Consider ignoring results for those models and see what happens with simulations at $5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000$ elements.